# There is any way to reuse data on json-ld?

Tags: json, seo, schema.org, json-ld

There is some way to reuse data in json-ld?

I have a WebSite and an Organization schemas with name, url and social links on it, i'm trying to get a better Google SEO and maybe one Google Graph Card like this:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/enhance-site

My json-ld is something like this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
[
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "WebSite",
      "name": "Name",
      "url": "http://www.example.com"
    },
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "Organization",
      "name": "Name",
      "url": "http://www.example.com",
      "sameAs": [
        "https://twitter.com/example"
      ]
    }
]
</script>
```

There is some way to not repeat name and url in both schemas?

And am I doing right? i really need the Organization schema to get these social links on the google card? Or the "sameAs" key could be in the WebSite schema?

I am following this guides:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitename

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/social-profile-links

Comment: Do you include the JSON-LD from your question exactly like this in your `script` element? AFAIK this shouldn’t work (having `[`…`]` at the top level).

Comment: Yes, it is on the script element, i'll add this to the code, thanks ;)
But, when i test it on google tester it works fine: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/
And on http://json-ld.org/playground/ works nice too.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I always thought you have to use `@graph` explicitly (the "Compacted"/"Flattened" output from json-ld.org/playground shows that it adds `@graph` automatically in that case).